# NSWindow frozen while simulating mouse down event

Tags: objective-c, mouseevent, nswindow, nsevent, cgeventtap

After receiving a mouse down event, my `NSWindow` is frozen. I'm unable to capture which threads hang in Xcode. I'm using the following code to simulate a mouse event:

```
CGEventSourceRef eventSource = CGEventSourceCreate(kCGEventSourceStateHIDSystemState);
CGEventRef event = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(eventSource, eventType, mouseLocation, mouseButton);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, event);
CFRelease(event);
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: If I send a mouse down/Up event on OS X default application like system preferences, disk utility and so on. Here It working properly. Which means I have to handle anything in my application window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed runloop mode from NSDefaultRunLoopMode to NSRunLoopCommonModes and It works.